# Insert data into database Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I try to save some data I get into a form in the database but I don't know how to do it.

Currently, here is what I have in the database (I try to add articles). As you can see I already have 2 of them but I set them using directly the CMS.
Now I would like to be able to modify these data (for exemple the title of an article) and even add new full articles if possible.

[image: records]

To get the articles this is what I am doing (it works).

```
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
    $query->condition('type', 'Article');
    $items_ids = $query->execute();
    $items = Node::loadMultiple($items_ids);
```

Now how to set some modification like saying the title for the article 2 is "title 2 changed"

Thanks for your assistance

Comment: It's best practice to not edit the database fields directly. Doing so could cause undesired behavior, especially with revisions.

Comment: Instead, I would recommend looking into using `Node::save()` or similar.  This would keep the revision history in tact.

Example:
```$node = Node::load($nid);
$node->setTitle('My New Title!!!!!!11!');
$node->save();```